# Can I Scramble a Dictonary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
a = {1 : True, 2 : False, 3 : True, 4 : False, etc}
```

How can I scramble the values to get something like this?

```
a = {1 : True, 2 : True, 3 : False, 4 : False, etc}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, what were the results and why were there not satisfactory? What was the problem?

Comment: So what exactly has been scrambled? Swapping keys and values? Flipping boolean values at random? There is no standard definition of 'scrambling', you need to provide one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to randomly assign a key to a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "scrambling" you mean randomly rearranging key-value pairings, you can do it in one line like so:

```
from random import sample

a = dict(zip(a, sample(a.values(), len(a))))
```

This isn't as efficient as using `shuffle`, however.

Also, beware that in Python 3, `dict.values` returns a [`dict_values` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296716/what-is-dict-keys-dict-items-and-dict-values) that doesn't behave as you'd expect.  You'd therefore need to write the following:

```
a = dict(zip(a, sample(list(a.values()), len(a))))
```

---

Comment: Nice, good use of `random.sample`.

Comment: @zondo Thanks, good catch!

Comment: Sure, but what if the OP wanted boolean values randomly flipped instead? The question doesn't define what they mean by 'scrambling'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True; I've clarified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a cleaner way, but `random.shuffle` on the dictionary values should get the job done.

```
from random import shuffle

a = {1 : True, 2 : False, 3 : True, 4 : False}

values = list(a.values())
shuffle(values)

shuffled = dict(zip(a, values))
# {1: True, 2: False, 3: False, 4: True}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

randValues = a.values()
random.shuffle(randValues)

for k in a:
    a[k] = randValues.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this:

```
>>> a = {1 : True, 2 : False, 3 : True, 4 : False}
>>> import random
>>> for key in a:
...     val = random.choice([True, False])
...     a[key] = val
...
>>> a
{1: True, 2: True, 3: True, 4: False}
```