# Histogram from NetworkX Degree Values - Python 2 vs. Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have the following code, which worked in Python 2.7, using NetworkX. Basically, it just plots a histogram of degree nodes like so:

```
plt.hist(nx.degree(G).values())
plt.xlabel('Degree')
plt.ylabel('Number of Subjects')
plt.savefig('network_degree.png') #Save as file, format specified in argument
```

[image]

When I try running this same code under Python 3, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 71, in <module>
    plt.hist(nx.degree(G).values())
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2958, in hist
    stacked=stacked, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1812, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5960, in hist
    x = _normalize_input(x, 'x')
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5902, in _normalize_input
    "{ename} must be 1D or 2D".format(ename=ename))
ValueError: x must be 1D or 2D
```

I'm just now starting to mess around with Python 3, using what I hoped would be pretty straightforward code. What's changed?

Comment: Support for dict views just merged to master https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/6787

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python2 the `dict.values` method returns a list.
In Python3, it returns [a `dict_values` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7296716/190597):

```
In [197]: nx.degree(G).values()
Out[197]: dict_values([2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Since `plt.hist` accepts a list, but not a `dict_values` object, convert the `dict_values` to a list:

```
  plt.hist(list(nx.degree(G).values()))
```

Answer (score 7):

For Networkx 2.1 they change the type of return for nx.degree(G), it's a different type called ***DegreeView***, but if you make a simple conversion the plot will be ok

```
plt.hist(list(dict(nx.degree(G)).values()))
plt.show()
```

[image: This is a histogram of Random Graph]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the accepted one is outdated now.