# Why is it that when I print a dictionary's keys there is dict_keys in front of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I do:

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 'randy'}

print(d.keys())
```

The result is:

```
dict_keys(['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Why is there the `dict_keys`? Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: `print(list(d.keys())`, or `print(" ".join(str(key) for key in d.keys()))`, depending on what output format you'd like.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296716/what-is-dict-keys-dict-items-and-dict-values , for the how and why.

Comment: The short answer is: because it's a dict_keys object.

Answer (score 8):

Convert it to a list.

```
>>> print(list(d.keys()))
['z', 'x', 'y']
```

Comment: My eyes deceive me! I think I just saw Ignacio suggest `list(d.keys())`!?

Comment: @JonClements: It's more explicit than `list(d)`, even though both will have the same result.